# Where does my data Object go WF / EF?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

Lets say I have a long running Workflow Statemachine, in which I store an Order.  I have an MVC Application in which many different changes happen to the Order from various forms.  And none of these is Workflow related except Status and StatusDate.

Most updates to Order are just calculations and CRUD operations.  As the order changes states, Do I keep the whole Order in workflow, use workflow persistence, and figure out how to get all my other updates into workflow, or do I store the order myself in my table using EF/L2S, and then pass the Order I'm working on into workflow, let the StateMachine update the State, and pass the order back as an out arguement.  Or..... could I have a Status/State field on the Order object, like a Guid, that is a pointer to an OrderStatus object that is created and kept in the long running workflow with persistence of it's own.

I like the last option, but what if I need query for all order that are in a state of shipped, or backordered, and have a particular StatusDate? And each one is in its own instance of the workflow?  Can I query the workflow host for all workflow instances with a State of "Shipped" and ?  StatusDate <= Now?  FYI... I'm using WF4.5

Comment: Each case is a case and there's no final answer to your question, at least without knowning you business logic. I've been in a couple projects with similar problems and learnt some things the hard way so take this as small tips. 1) always try to keep as much data as possible on your side and not on workflow side. Workflow is for logic, not for persistence. You can't (at least you shouldn't) be querying the workflow database to get the order state. 2) Initialize an order on your side and fire the respective workflow with a correlation id (e.g: the db's orderId itself).

Comment: 3) consider using WorkflowServices+AppFabric. 4) call the workflow through ReceiveAndReply activities, let the workflow do it's thing and return the values to you. then you can persist them the way you want, on "your" side. 5) workflow doesn't need to known the order state. It only needs to known its state which is where it currently is (the activity) no more and no less than that

Comment: Sorry for not giving you a real answer. I guess you're trying to find the best architecture for your problem but it's hard to give a more concise answer when the question is so broad and my context is zero :)